# How to update Hangfire to use the updated DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, hangfire

### Background

I've inherited an ASP.NET (C#) application that implements hangfire.
This solution includes `HangfirePortal` and multiple projects for different jobs. 
Each project in this solution has a reference to `OurFramework`, and we recently updated `OurFramework` to use a new SQL server. 
Other applications that have a reference to `OurFramework` are updated just fine and it uses the new SQL server, but this application with hangfire is still using the old SQL server, which means (I believe) that its reference to `OurFramework` is the old version. 
I've been trying to figure this out for days. I'd appreciate any advice on this.

### What I've done

- Moved the Hangfire database from the old SQL server to the new SQL server (used SQL comparison)
- Re-published HangfirePortal
- Re-referenced `OurFramework` (deleted and added again)
- Re-built the application and copied updated files over the server for Hangfire (This is what I do when I make changes to the client side and update the server, which has been working fine)
- Tests the framework using C# Interactive - this resulted in using the updated framework. Worked just fine (because it saves data to the new SQL server)
- Debugged a unit test that uses a class in `OurFramework` - this resulted in using teh updated framework. Worked just fine
- Tested the same class with other applications - worked just fine

Since it seems to be working fine locally and also other applications are working fine, I'm thinking that the hangfire project is not properly updated in the server.

### Code

This is an example of a job in the client.
This project has a reference to `OurFramework.Operations`, and this is the one that has been changed to use a new database

```
using OurFramework.Operations.Logging;

public class SampleJob
{
    public void TestLog()
        {
            LogWriter _log = new LogWriter();
            _log.TryLog("HangfireTest", "This should be stored in the new database");
        }
}
```

When I run this code locally, I see that it's using the new database and the log successfully saves to the new database. So it looks like it's using the updated version of framework.

There also is a project called Core, which keeps all the .dll files in a directory called `libraries`. 
This `libraries` contains the following files:

> - OurFramework.Operations.dll
> - OurFramework.Operations.dll.config
> - OurFramework.Operations.pdb
> - OurFramework.Data.dll
> - OurFramework.Data.dll.config
> - OurFramework.Data.pdb

`OurFramework.Data.dll.config` lists connectionString for the `OurFramework.Operations.Logging` and it points to the new database.

After rebuilding the whole solution, I copy the modified files in `MySolution\bin\Debug` and paste them into `HangfireServer\Hangfire`.

Answer (score 0):

Hangfire needs it's own dedicated server that needs to be connected to it in order for it to work. The only steps that you need to take is the creation and the connection of such server, hangfire should make all the necessary tables and columns. With that being said, your dilemma leads me to believe that your hangfire project is simply using the old connection string for the old framework. Take a look at the connection string in hangfire and see where its pointing.

Take a look at these resources:

[http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/processing-background-jobs.html)

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/processing-background-jobs.html

Comment: I have multiple connection strings and they all have been updated to the new server ... :( Hangfire job itself has been working fine, and it has been using the database in the new SQL Server. It's the framework that keeps using the old database instead of the new database..:(